# How do I add a button to a spreadsheet and remove borders from a particular cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, spreadsheet

I have two queries regarding the following Excel file:

[image]

1. I would like a button on this excel sheet whose name should be “Save as PDF”.

   - When I press this button it should save the excel sheet’s all data into PDF at the path- M:\formats\ ‘File Name’
   - ‘File Name’ should be the value of cell No H8.
   - In another words when I click “Save as PDF” button it should save the excel file in pdf form, into the above mentioned path and also with the name whichever is written in cell no H8.
   - For example if the name ANDREW PITTERSON is written in H8 cell then it should save with the same name I.e. ANDREW PITTERSON.
2. I want to remove the line which is showing in this snapshot.

   - For this I have tried to uncheck gridlines in view tab, but here the problem is it hides all gridlines while I want some of the gridlines to be shown (cell no H8 is one of them).
   - The another thing which I have tried to solve this problem is that I put ‘all borders’ from home tab.
   - But it creates another problem, when I take print out of the sheet it shows borders.
   - I do not want any border to be shown when I take print out of the sheet.
   - So is there any way to remove only selected lines from the sheet as shown in the image.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please help me friends...it is very important...

Comment: For the second part of your question, merge rows 7 & 8 if that is an acceptable way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for the button

```
Sub Button1_Click()
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat 
        Type:=xlTypePDF, 
        Filename:=Range("H8").Value, 
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, 
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, 
        OpenAfterPublish:= False
End Sub
```

The easiest way to learn doing this by recording a macro (which is how I did)